# Adding SSL certificates on the fly in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, ssl-certificate, https, httpd

I'm creating a website builder in which users get the option to host the site on their own custom domain via setting the CNAME in their DNS.

Everything works great on http:// but for https:// I'm using Letsencrypt to generate SSL certificates for their CNAME domain.

My problem is how to add these SSL certificates to apache.conf?

I can write a cron job to modify httpd.conf and add it but that means I have to restart the apache server and it doesn't sound like a solution when i have more than 50 domains.

Any ideas how people make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Apache should reload configuration on SIGHUP signal. E.g. If you call `systemctl reload httpd` or `service httpd reload`, your configuration should be updated.

Also, there is no need to edit httpd.conf, you could add include directive in httpd.conf and create one additional file for each domain.

Comment: Thanks but how does it scale? The config file will become pretty huge after 50 or say 500 domains.. Wouldn't that make things slow down?

Comment: I don't have Apache with 50 or 500 domains, but config reload - normal operation for Apache. I think it shouldn't affect performance.

Comment: I might have at some point, maybe even in thousands, since any user can add as many CNAME domains as she wants

Comment: With thousands domain you could have problem with Apache Performance. At this case I could offer you to use `nginx` as proxy. Terminate SSL connection on nginx and then proxy all requests to Web-servers in backend.

Comment: Yes that does sound like an option if I can't do it via Apache.. Nginx does have a support for dynamic ssl via lua-resty-auto-ssl.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to execute one command to reload the httpd without restarting it and it works like a charm.

```
httpd -k graceful
```

any doubt ? check:

```
man httpd
```

If you're looking to add SSL certificates into your apache server, I'd suggest inside of your apache directory create a directory named SSL, and a file named SSL/httpd-ssl.conf
add the certificated using below statements:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/<certificate_file>.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/<private_key_file>.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/<intermediate>.crt
```

include this file into your httpd.conf, execute `httpd -k graceful` and you're good to go.